# Formatar String com DateFormat usando uma TimeZone não está funcionando

Tags: java, string, datetime, formatação

No meu web service, existe um endpoint que me retorna um timestamp em `UTC` e possuo um método que gera uma data formatada a partir deste timestamp:

`formatDate(1432313391, "UTC");`

```
public String formatDate(long date, String timeZone) 
{
    //Neste caso, o Locale está como ENGLISH (default do aparelho)
    DateFormat f = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM,DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.getDefault());
    f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
    return f.format(date);
}
```

Mas por algum motivo esse método está me retornando a seguinte String:

> Jan 17, 1970 1:51:53 PM

Sendo que, se converter esta data em [algum conversor](http://www.epochconverter.com/) ela fica como:

> 5/22/2015, 1:49:51 PM

Alguém tem ideia do motivo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O conversor que você está usando não está considerando o tempo em milisegundos, mas em segundos. Usando o valor `1432313391` [nesse outro conversor](http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators) a saída para a sua entrada dá o mesmo resultado do que o código em Java:

> Sat Jan 17 1970 11:51:53 GMT-0200 (Horário brasileiro de verão)

Para chegar na data que você quer adicione `000` ao final do valor que você havia usado para ver que a data é exatamente igual a saída do site que você usou como teste, só que no site não está considerando o UTC, por isso está dando três horas de diferença. Assim:

```
formatDate(1432313391000L, "UTC");
```

Saída:

> 22/05/2015 16:49:51

Se você já recebe a variável com o número em segundos você pode multiplicar por `1000` dentro do método que formata sua String. Exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(formatDate(1432313391, "UTC"));
}

public static String formatDate(long date, String timeZone) {
    //Neste caso, o Locale está como ENGLISH (default do aparelho)
    DateFormat f = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.getDefault());
    f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
    return f.format(date * 1000); //transforma de segundos para milisegundos
}
```

Comment: Funcionou! Mas, existe alguma maneira de "forcar" a utilizar milissegundos ao invés de segundos através do `DateFormat` ou `Calendar`?

Comment: Não, conforme pode ver aqui: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long) ele espera a entrada em milisegundos, você pode fazer uma multiplicação por `1000` antes de passar o valor, caso você já receba o número em segundos, assim: `return f.format(date * 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a classe [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) da seguinte maneira:

```
public String formatDate(long date, String timeZone) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(date);
    DateFormat f = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM,   DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.getDefault());
    return f.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

> // May 22, 2015 1:36:59 PM

Comment: A data em UTC vem do meu web service, não é a data do aparelho

Comment: Você passa a data no setTimeInMillis

Comment: O bug continua!

Comment: Não precisa setar o timezone, editei a resposta.

Comment: Continua retornando o mesmo valor para mim :/

Comment: Qual o valor que está vindo do servidor?

Answer (score 0):

A partir do Java 8 (ou, se for no Android, a partir da API Level 26 (necessário *minSdkVersion* >= 26, não basta ter *compileSdkVersion* >= 26)), você pode usar a [API `java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052).

Neste caso, não precisa multiplicar o valor do timestamp por 1000, bastando passá-lo diretamente para um [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html), e em seguida convertendo-o para um [`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) (que corresponde a uma data e hora em um timezone específico), e por fim formatando. Você vai precisar destes `import`'s:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
```

E o código fica assim:

```
public static String formatDate(long date, String timeZone) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
        // usa os formatos localizados
        .ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM, FormatStyle.MEDIUM);
    return Instant
        // converte os segundos para um Instant
        .ofEpochSecond(date)
        // converte para o timezone
        .atZone(ZoneId.of(timeZone))
        // formata
        .format(formatter);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(formatDate(1432313391, "UTC"));
}
```

Por padrão, o [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) já usa o *locale default* da JVM, então não precisa usar `Locale.getDefault()`. Mas se quiser mudar para um *locale* diferente do *default*, basta fazer:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
    // usa os formatos localizados
    .ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM, FormatStyle.MEDIUM);
    // seta o locale
    .withLocale(new Locale("pt", "BR")));
```